# How to create spinner for arrays from xml and from java code?

Tags: android

I am creating an app of spinner with two cases:

1. when array is in XML code
2. when array is in java code.

However I'm getting several errors

```
package com.example.spinnerexample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.SpinnerAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;
import spinnerexample.R;

public class SpinnerActivity extends Activity {

    void showToast(CharSequence message) {
        CharSequence message1 = null;
        Toast.makeText(this, message1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Spinner spinner1;
        Spinner s1 = (Spinner) findViewbyId(R.id.spinner1);
        ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.colors, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        s1.setAdapter(adapter);
        s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long id) {
        AdapterView<SpinnerAdapter> s1;
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String ss = s1.getSelectedItem().toString();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), ss, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    {
        Spinner s2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        String[] planets = {"Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars", "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Neptune", "Pluto"};
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, planets);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        s2.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

Comment: If your code is giving you errors, could you add them to your question?

Comment: Your code is strange, did you copied it? :D

Comment: When should the last code with spinner 2 execute? I've got solution but i dont know where to put these lines

Answer (score 0):

I was just curious about the issue. Discovered everything - OP -> please, first learn basic programming, and then go to android, and then go for fancy stuff like Adapters and Spinners - thats my advice, except if you are a student, students doesnt need these stuff.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;
import spinnerexample.R;

public class SpinnerActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {

    Spinner s1;
    Spinner s2;

    void showToast(CharSequence message) {
        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        //initialization
        s1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        s2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);

        //First spinner
        ArrayAdapter resourceAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.colors, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        resourceAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        s1.setAdapter(resourceAdapter);
        s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        //Second spinner
        String[] planets = {"Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars", "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Neptune", "Pluto"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, planets);
        arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        s2.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
        String message = "";
        if (adapterView == s1) {
            message = s1.getSelectedItem().toString();
        } else if (adapterView == s2) {
            message = s2.getSelectedItem().toString();
        }

        showToast(message);
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        //Blank
    }
}
```